# In Java, sort hash map by its key.length()

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator, treemap

i have a hashmap like this:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
map.put("java",4);
map.put("go",2);
map.put("objective-c",11);
map.put("c#",2);
```

now i want to sort this map by its key length,  if two keys length are equal (e.g   go  and  c# both length 2), then sorted by alphba order.
so the outcome i expect to get is something like:

printed result:
objective-c, 11
java, 4
c#, 2
go, 2

here is my own attamp, but it doesnt work at all...

```
      HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
          map.put("java",4);
          map.put("go",2);
          map.put("objective-c",11);
          map.put("c#",2);

      Map<String,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(
                new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                        return s1.length().compareTo(s2.length());
                    }
                }
        );
```

actually the  'compareTo'  method appears as red (not be able to compile)....
please someone help me with some code example...i am a bit confusing with how to use comparator class to customize compare object...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The compiler is complaining because you cannot call `compareTo` on an `int`. The correct way to sort the map is the following:

```
Map<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(
    new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
        }
});
```

The first two conditions compare the lengths of the two `String`s and return a positive or a negative number accordingly. The third condition would compare the `String`s lexicographically if their lengths are equal.

Answer (score 6):

You call `String#length()`, which returns a primitive `int`. You need the static method `Integer.compare(int,int)`. If you are on Java 8, you can save yourself a lot of typing:

```
Map<String,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(
        Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
                  .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```

Comment: sir your out put is {}?

Comment: My code doesn't attempt any output, but if you're asking about the String representation of an empty map, then you are right.

Comment: I posted this question. if you can answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905445/apply-distinct-function-on-treemap

Comment: This answer is not correct, if you have two keys `"Foo"` and `"foo"`, i.e. same length and same letters with different case then the second put will override the first one, that is why there should be a lexicographic comparison if the length is equal.

Comment: @A4L True, it was an omission. I update the answer so that the comparison falls back to the default string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
  return o1.length() == o2.length() ? o1.compareTo(o2) : o1.length() - o2.length();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because `length()` doesn't define `compareTo` method thats why you see error. To correct it use `Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());` updated code below

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put("java",4);
        map.put("go",2);
        map.put("objective-c",11);
        map.put("c#",2);


        Map<String,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(
                new Comparator<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                        return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
                    }
                }
        );

        treeMap.putAll(map);

        System.out.println(treeMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: when you run your code, the outcome is {c#=2, java=4, objective-c=11}. the question is where is the "go",2?

Comment: Its due to the fact that TreeMap is using Comparator and comparator is defined to treat 2 strings of equal length as same. Since OP was playing with TreeMap so i extended his/her answer to correct only the Comparator part.

Comment: oh cool what do you think about my answer? since the op did not mention that using treemap is mandatory I used another style

Comment: code is not working as expected, keys with the same length got overriden

Answer (score 1):

> If using the **TreeMap** is **not mandatory**

**Explantion**: Define a `Comaprator` , and next step, define a list so we can add all map entries into a list. At the end, sort the list by defined `Comaprator`

**Code**:

```
 Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> byMapValues = 
         (Map.Entry<String,Integer> left, Map.Entry<String,Integer> right) ->left.getValue().compareTo(right.getValue());

 List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.addAll(map.entrySet());
 Collections.sort(list, byMapValues);
 list.forEach( i -> System.out.println(i));
```

**Output**:

```
c#=2
go=2
java=4
objective-c=11
```

Note: **get sorted by number**

if there is need to do comparison based on key, the following line can be used.

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> byMapKeys = 
             (Map.Entry<String,Integer> left, Map.Entry<String,Integer> right) -> left.getKey().compareTo(right.getKey());
```

Answer (score -2):

The Comparator should be:

```
new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does not work. If the two strings are of same length, and using a TreeMap to sort, it will consider String keys of the same length as duplicates and remove them.