# Apply Distinct Function on TreeMap

Tags: java, lambda, distinct, java-8, treemap

Code:

```
   Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> test = new TreeMap<>();
    test.put(1, new HashSet<>());
    test.put(2, new HashSet<>());
    test.put(3, new HashSet<>());
    test.put(4, new HashSet<>());

    test.get(1).add("1");
    test.get(2).add("2");
    test.get(3).add("2");
    test.get(4).add("3, 33");

    //get value of treemap and get rid of the duplicate by using distinct and printout 
    //at the end
    test.values().stream().distinct().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
```

output:

```
[1]
[2]
[3, 33]
```

**My question is how I can printout the key and value at the same time without having duplicate value?**

Expected Result:

```
  1= [1]
  2= [2]
  3= [3, 33]
```

**I even try below code, yet it gives me the treemap with the duplicate values:**

Code:

```
   List<Map.Entry<Integer, HashSet<String>>> list = new ArrayList<>();
   list.addAll(test.entrySet());
   list.stream().distinct().forEach( i -> System.out.println(i));
```

Output:

```
1=[1]
2=[2]
3=[2]
4=[3, 33]
```

Comment: Why is it `3= [3, 33]`? What happened to `4`? Which key should remain for `2`?

Comment: this is expected result. as you see 2 and 3 have the same value which is 2. Is it even possible to have my expected result?

Comment: No, your expected result doesn't make much sense considering you want the key and value of an entry. `[3, 33]` should be mapped to `4`. You'll have to define how the mapping should behave.

Comment: so what do you mean by define how the mapping should behave?

Comment: Currently, your request of _how I can printout the key and value at the same time without having duplicate value_ doesn't really match your expected results. Give us something that does.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think I just need a counter that is all, but I do not know how to inject it to my code.

Comment: I don't understand anymore. You don't seem to know what you're asking...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61466/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: I deleted my answer, as I cannot continue working on this. Unfortunately you have to keep a second collection for checking duplicates.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose why I was looking to see your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 8 Distinct by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

Comment: @StuartMarks was it on tree map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        x -> x,
                        (a, b) -> a
                )
        ).values()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Edit:**

Explanation: this snippet will take the stream of entries and put them into a map of value to entry while discarding duplicates (see javadoc for [Collectors#toMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)).  It then takes the values of that map as a collection.  The result is the collection of map entries that are distinct by `Map.Entry::getValue`.

**Edit 2:**

From your comments I think I understand what you are trying to do.  You are using this TreeSet as a 1-based list and you want keys to collapse as you remove duplicate values.  Is that correct?  Maybe you can explain why you are doing this instead of just using a list.

Streams aren't well-suited for this sort of approach, so this will not be pretty, but here you go:  Stream the values, eliminate duplicates, collect into a list, then turn the list back into a map.

```
test.values().stream()
        .distinct()
        .collect(
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(),
                        lst -> IntStream.range(0, lst.size()).boxed().collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(i -> i + 1, i -> lst.get(i))
                        )
                )
        ).entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

output:
 1=[1]
 2=[2]
 3=[3, 33]
```

Comment: so no there is no duplicate value? can you plz post up the outcome of this code?

Comment: I am not near a compiler, but it should print 1=[1]
2=[2]
4=[3, 33]

Comment: @KickButtowski  In your setup, you have `test.get(4).add("3, 33");`, so it will print 4=[3,33].

Comment: is not possible that key become 3 not 4? plz explain ur approaches so I can accept it

Comment: @KickButtowski Can you clarify where you expect 3 to come from?  In the original TreeMap, the set ["3,33"] is associated with key 4.

Comment: I thought when u get rid of duplicate values keys are shrunk too cuz 2 and 3 have same value. what's is going to happen key three in ur approaches?

Comment: @KickButtowski I added an edit.  See if that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusion as you say you want *the* key for distinct values but duplicate values obviously have duplicate keys. It’s not clear why you expect the key `2` for the value `2` in your example as the value `2` is present two times in the source map, having the keys `2` *and* `3`.

The following code will gather all keys for duplicates:

```
test.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
     Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
  .forEach((value,keys) -> System.out.println(keys+"\t= "+value));
```

It will print:

```
 [1]    = [1]
 [2, 3] = [2]
 [4]    = [3, 33]
```

for your example map. It’s up to you to pick up the key `2` from the key list `[2, 3]` if you have a rule for the selection.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Map<Integer, HashSet<String>> test = new TreeMap<>();
        test.put(1, new HashSet<String>());
        test.put(2, new HashSet<String>());
        test.put(3, new HashSet<String>());
        test.put(4, new HashSet<String>());

        test.get(1).add("1");
        test.get(2).add("2");
        test.get(3).add("2");
        test.get(4).add("3, 33");

    int count = 0;
    HashSet<String> distinctValues = new HashSet<>();
    test.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
      HashSet<String> entryValues = new HashSet<>();
      entryValues.addAll(entry.getValue());
      // ignore any values you've already processed
      entryValues.removeAll(distinctValues);
      if (!entryValues.isEmpty()) {
          System.out.println(++count + " = " + entryValues);
          distinctValues.addAll(entryValues);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I want to apply lambda

Comment: Sorry I just realised I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: You just need to keep track of the set of values you've processed so far - see edited answer

Comment: I totally appreciate your answer and I will take a look at it later, but my question is how I can use Java 8 to accomplish that

Comment: I don't think in this case you're gaining anything by using lambdas. Instead of the for-loop it would just be `test.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> ` everything else is the same