# Sort Entry Set of String, Integer by more than one field

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator, compareto

Have a Map<String, Integer> and trying to sort on value and length of String. I am trying to compare two different things in the statement so don't know if I need two different statements.  This is being used to compare digit root so the String length and then the digit root is the value and the value.

For example:

```
("103",4); (1+0+3 == 4)
("4",4); (4 ==4)
("11101",4); (1+1+1+0+1 == 4)
("5",5); (5 == 5 )
("1003",4); (1+0+0+3 == 4)
```

But `("103",4) > ("4",4)` because the length of "103" > "4", and `("11101",4) > ("103",4);`, length `"11101" > "103"`

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) { int length = o1.getKey().length().compareTo(o2.getKey().length());
if(length != 0) {
 return length;
}
return (o1.getValue()).compareTo(o2.getValue());
}
});
```

**Edit Answered to the above Question(Also, response given)**

```
 Map<String,Integer> unsortMap = new.
                        TreeMap<String,Integer>();

unsortMap.put("103",4);
unsortMap.put("4",4);
unsortMap.put("11101",4);   
unsortMap.put("5",5);
unsortMap.put("1003",4); Map<String,

 Integer> result =unsortMap.entrySet().stream() .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)) )
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) .collect(Collectors.toMap
     (Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new)); 

 System.println(result);
```

Comment: so what do you mean by on value and length of String?

Comment: `Collections.sort(List<T> list)` is for list . You can use TreeMap instead

Comment: I can guess this is what you are asking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899929/in-java-sort-hash-map-by-its-key-length

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to sort by the lenght of the key on the map??

Comment: Added explanation in the problem statement.  I need to have the values also ordered so though 4 and 22 have value of 4 I need 4 to come before 22.

Comment: I am working with a linked list trying to sort the entrySet from the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **If you already have a map, and you want to order it, by lenght key, and by value then:**

```
Map<String,Integer> unsortMap = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();

unsortMap.put("103",4);
unsortMap.put("4",4);
unsortMap.put("11101",4);
unsortMap.put("5",5);
unsortMap.put("1003",4);

Map<String, Integer> result = unsortMap.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))

        ).sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));


System.out.println(result);

out => {4=4, 103=4, 1003=4, 11101=4, 5=5}
```

Comment: I get that it can't find Function.  I think this is what I am looking for but when I get to this sort I already have the treemap @Damian Lattenero

Comment: @April_Nara I updated the answer! don't forget to accept if it was usefull

Comment: It doesn't do what I want it to now though.  I still need it to sort the value. the second solution only orders by length.  I do appreciate the help.

Comment: @April_Nara let me know if now I understood your question, and if that is your expected output

Comment: That's an incorrect output. I want to also sort on value. First you'd never get 22=7 as the digit root is 4 so it would need to be {4=4, 22=4, 103=4, 23=5} would be what I need. @Damian Lattenero

Comment: @April_Nara but who is bigger? ("103", 1) or ("9", 3) ? because "103" is larger than "9", but 1 < 3... so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158900/discussion-between-april-nara-and-damian-lattenero).

Comment: Thank you. I was familiar with the sort in 8 but was still attempting in 7.

Comment: @April_Nara I have always loved to help :)

Comment: @DamianLattenero this the nice way to sort :).

Answer (score 1):

You can compare in this way, if you are aiming to sort with length.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> o1, Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (o1.getKey().length() == o2.getKey().length()) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (o1.getKey().length() > o2.getKey().length()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: That's a good answer, and a plus one ;), you can do it shorter, take a look at my answer if you want

Comment: Thank you :), I checked and I really like that way, but reason why I use multiple if statement because it make code bit debug friendly :P in general.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the problem of sorting them by value as well.

Comment: Sorry for delay in response, but now I have one question to @April_Nara, and its basis how much I understand your question and please correct me if I m wrong. You wanted to sort it with key and sorting is based on sum of individual key. If this the case then why you are using String as key?? It can easily be done with Integer as sum of key.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said *why* it doesn't work. What happens when you try?

In Java, a `Map` is not meant to be sorted, it is meant for fast access.
However, implementations like `TreeMap` maintain a deterministic ordering, and can be sorted. Your code suggests you are trying to sort the Map's `EntrySet`. A Java `Set` also has no order, and cannot be sorted.

I suggest you either utilise a `NavigableMap` like a `TreeMap`, or work with a `List` rather than a `Set`. A Java `List` has an order, and can be sorted using `Collections.sort(...)`.

There are a number of reasons why your existing code may not be working. For one thing, you are attempting to call `compareTo`on an `int` (at `o1.getKey().length().compareTo(...)`). This is not possible. You could instead use:

```
Ints.compare(o1.getKey().length(), o2.getKey().length());
```

Comment: The question isn't really being addressed because, I am not sure if I can but I think I should, be able to compare two things in the compare statement.

Comment: the question is updated, please check your answer now